# Mozilla PdfJs Operations

Tags: pdf, pdf.js

given a PDF that is rendered in the browser using pdfjs, are there functions to do the following basic view operations:

- rotate
- flip
- zoom

If not, what are the best strategies I can use to do the operations above?

Comment: The pdf.js script does have a [website](http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/), a [demo](http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/web/viewer.html), and a github [page](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js), so why don't you read the documentation and find out? Also have a look at the [source](http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/build/pdf.js), and unless you have a lot of free time on your hands I'm guessing you don't want to mess with that thing.

Comment: I have looked at the examples and read the source. There are functions to do zoom but I don't see any function that changes rotate degrees. There is also no proprty for rotate in source. However, scouring the src files I see some a rotate property in src/api.js. I am just asking if it is possible to do rotation and flipping.

Comment: @arvinsim Unfortunately the pdf.js API is still very nascent and not that fleshed out. There are many operations that are specific to the viewer and not exposed via API. I suggest going through the code or looking for help on #pdfjs at irc.mozilla.org (very helpful people there!).

Answer (score 6):

You can set rotation when you getting viewport form PdfPage object:

```js
var viewport = pdfPage.getViewport(scale, rotation);
```

If you want to immediately set all the parameters, you can clone viewport, created with scale = 1:

```js
var defaultViewport = pdfPage.getViewport(1);
var neededViewport = defaultViewport.clone({scale: needScale, rotation: needRotation, dontFlip: true});
```